# Add multiple filter tags on Shopify store

Tags: filter, shopify, liquid

**Problem explanation:**

I have a Shopify store and I want to add multiple filters for tags, my product tags looks like this

product 1: Face shape diamond, frame size medium, frame shape aviator

product 2: Face shape heart, frame size small, frame shape square

product 3: Face shape square, frame size large, frame shape cat eye

And what I need is 3 filters (select box),

1st filter title: Face Shape
1st filter options: diamond, heart, square

2nd filter title: Frame size
2nd filter options: small, large, medium

3rd filter title: Frame Shape
3rd filter options: cat eye, aviator, square

Then when the user click on each one it filters the products accordingly

What's happening now is it filters only according to 1 tag, then when I add the second filter by tag it removes the first one & filter by the second tag

So for example, if I filters by face shape = diamond, the results are correctly showing, however when I add the second filter by frame size = small, it shows the results of frame size = small disregarding the face shape

**The code**

My theme doesn't allow filters so I downloaded Search & Discovery application and added 1 filter for the tags but I cannot add more than 1 filter of any type on the application

I added 1 tag filter from the app, and tried to make the other 2 filters manually like so

```
//this is to get all the tags of the products and remove duplicates
<details class="filter-group">
   //this is the filter title
    <summary class="filter-group-summary">
        <div>
        <span>Frame Size</span>
        </div>
        <div>
        {% render 'armament-icon' with icon: 'arrow-right', classes: "w-10 custom-filter__right-icon" %}
        </div>
    </summary>

   //this is checkboxes with all the tags values of the frame size
    <div class="filter-group-display">
        <ul class="filter-group-display__list">
        {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
            {% if tag contains 'SIZE_' %}
                <li class="filter-group-display__list-item pb-2">
                <label for="Filter-{{ forloop.index }}">
                    // when the form is submitted, take this name and put it in the url

                    <input type="checkbox"
                        name="filter.p.tag"
                        value="{{ tag }}"
                        id="Filter-{{ forloop.index }}"
                        {% if filter_value.count == 0 and filter_value.active == false -%}disabled{%- endif %}
                        data-armada-selector="custom_filter_checkbox"
                    > 
                    {{ tag | remove: "SIZE_" }}
                </label>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</details>



<script>
 let collection_handle = '{{collection.handle}}';
 let custom_loader = document.querySelector('#custom_loader');
 let custom_checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('[data-armada-selector="custom_filter_checkbox"]');
 let custom_filter_form = document.querySelector('[data-armada-selector="custom_filter-form-container"]');
 let custom_active_filters = document.querySelector('[data-armada-selector="active-filters"]');

let queryString;

custom_checkbox.forEach(checkbox => 
      checkbox.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        // take the form data & transform them into queryParam
        queryString = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(custom_filter_form)).toString();
        custom_loader.classList.remove('hidden')

        let fetch_url;
        if(window.location.href.includes("?sort") || window.location.href.includes("&sort")) 
        {
          const querySortString = window.location.search;
          const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(querySortString);
          const sort_by_value = urlParams.get('sort_by')
        
          fetch_url = '/collections/{{ collection.handle }}?' + queryString + "&sort_by="+sort_by_value
        }
        else fetch_url = '/collections/{{ collection.handle }}?' + queryString;
        
        fetch(fetch_url)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(data => {
            let html_div = document.createElement('div');
            let active_filter_div = document.createElement('div');
            
            html_div.innerHTML = data;
            active_filter_div.innerHTML = data;
            
            let html_dom = html_div.querySelector('[data-armada-selector="collection-grid-main"]').innerHTML;
            let active_filter_html_dom = html_div.querySelector('[data-armada-selector="active-filters"]').innerHTML;
            
            // replace the document grid section with the grid from api response
            document.querySelector('[data-armada-selector="collection-grid-main"]').innerHTML = html_dom;
            document.querySelector('[data-armada-selector="active-filters"]').innerHTML = active_filter_html_dom;
            
            // update url without refreshing the page 
            history.replaceState(null, null, fetch_url);
            custom_loader.classList.add('hidden');
          })
          .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
          .finally(() => custom_loader.classList.add('hidden'));
      })
    )
</script>
```

**URL structure in the browser**

`?filter.p.product_type=Acetate+Eyeglasses&filter.p.tag=FRAME+SHAPE_ROUND&filter.p.tag=SIZE_SMALL`

**What I think the solution is**

I think since having 2 inputs with the same name (filter.p.tag), the form is submitting only one of them and replacing the other but I have to have this name so the form takes the value & put it in the url as it should be & probably it's the url structure what's wrong but I'm not finding the resource of how to filter products by multiple tags

**What I tried**

In Shopify documentation, [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/navigation-search/filtering/storefront-filtering#:%7E:text=//%20Product%20tag,3), they say to add a coma in between the 2 tags
?filter.p.tag=FRAME+SHAPE_ROUND,SIZE_SMALL

But it's not working for me as well

Also I tried this url structure
`?filter.p.tag=FRAME+SHAPE_ROUND+AND+SIZE_SMALL`

But the result was no product found although of having multiple products with these 2 tags

I also tried
`?filter[p][tag][]=FRAME+SHAPE_ROUND&filter[p][tag][]=SIZE_SMALL`
And `?constraint=tag:FRAME+SHAPE_ROUND,SIZE_SMALL` And `?tags=FRAME+SHAPE_ROUND,SIZE_SMALL`

As suggested by ChatGPt, but still no results

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually updating an eyewear site right now.
The Custom Meta Fields should achieve your goal of frame shape AND color.
[Reference - filter behavior Shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/search-and-discovery/filters#:%7E:text=your%20filters.-,Filter%20behavior,-Filters%20that%20don%27t)

**Consider using the Custom Meta Fields like so:**

**Step 1 - Create Custom Field**

- Settings > Custom data > Product > Add definition
- Be sure to check off "Storefront" Access
- Select Type: Single line of text
- Check the box "limit to preset choices"
- List values

**Step 2 - Assign values to product**

- Scroll to bottom of product page
- Select 1 or more values
- *Hint: Product with color variants - use a Variant level field to map variant colors to their filter color.*

**Step 3 - Associate new field with filter**

- Apps Section (left panel under Sales Channels)
- Search & Discovery > View filters > Add filter

  - Select the appropriate field from Source list
  - Type the name you want users to see under Label

**Step 4 - Check filter/function in Customize Theme**

- Navigate to "Default Collection"
- On left panel, under Collection > Product grid
- Make sure "Enable filtering" is checked

**Front End View:**
[image]